# Splash Screen - white

Tags: android, splash-screen

For the splash screen I'm using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
    }
}, 3500);
```

And it's working, it shows my splash screen for 3 and a half seconds. But, when I'm starting the app, first the display is white for like a second and then it shows my splash screen. Since the code is working, could the problem be the mobile phone that I'm using instead an emulator? Or I need to add something to my code?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. The empty screen you see at first is because of cold start of your application. http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@ayushkhare/android-splash-screens-c02effd2db61)

Comment: The link @AyushKhare gave will help you.

Comment: what phone you are using for test?

Comment: You can change that white screen aswell. Actually, that should be the proper way to implement "Splash screen". Check this: https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White screen is caused by AppTheme. When app is initialize it shows default white screen before setting any views.

You can make that white screen disappear by just adding the following attribute to your AppTheme.

Just add

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground"><place here any drawable or color></item>
</style>
```

Let me know if it is helpful to you. Thanks!!!

Comment: I did that. I added it to styles.xml but now, instead of the white screen I have the backgorund, then comes splash activity. So, instead of the white screen I hva my @drawable/dog background

Comment: Yes that's the way to get rid of white screen

Answer (score 0):

Nope It's not a problem of your code. It also happens with my app. Seems that the white screen comes when android is loading the app itself. and if you are loading a lot at start only then it will take longer to load and hence bigger white screen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For my Splashscreen I'm using two activities which you also have to register in your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityMain"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In my Splash Activity I'm starting my main activity by an intent like following:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Runnable task = () -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        final AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVectorDrawableCompat =
                AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.animatedvector);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(animatedVectorDrawableCompat);

        final Animatable animatable = (Animatable) imageView.getDrawable();
        animatable.start();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(task, 1500);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the start of the main activity is delayed by a handler.

Hope this helps; I dont get white screens with this code ;-)

Comment: You will get white screen if app is cold starting and there is some initialization going on (for example DB creation in Applications onCreate or so)

Comment: I dont think so, because I'm finishing the first activity after the start of the main activity

Comment: doesn't matter as application is initialized before any activity content (layout) is shown. That's what cold start is about. Look here: http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts